# Very specific riddle

Tags: discussion

How can we judge if the subject of a riddle is too specific or not? I've seen some about not famous movies or books for instance, and I have the feeling that these riddles are too specific since the public able to answer them is very small (since you need a lot of general knowledge to know every book/movie).

Is that right to post a riddle that concern only a few people, maybe none?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's fine to post it, but it likely won't get a lot of attention, or a lot of votes if the answer turns out to be too obscure.  People tend to like "clever" riddles, which are hard because of a twist or trick of language.  If the puzzle is only hard because no one has heard of the answer, it generally isn't a very good puzzle, and won't receive many votes.

Comment: True. Also relevant: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2947/the-many-eyes-effect

Comment: The fact is that i was split in two types of thinking : either people will be bored and won't work on the solution or people will try hard, search everywhere on the web for clues etc... But now i'm pretty sure you're right and people won't care :) thanks